# How to make an AJAX request in plsql

Tags: ajax, plsql

I am trying to call a stored procedure from another stored procedure that looks something similar to that of the below code:

```
create or replace procedure hello_world is
v_first_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'ABC';
v_LAST_name  VARCHAR2(30) := 'XYZ';
BEGIN
htp.p('<HTML>');
htp.p('<HEAD>');
htp.p('<TITLE>Instructor Personal Info</TITLE>');
htp.p('</HEAD>');
htp.p('<BODY bgColor="#99CCCC">');
HTP.P('<input type="text" name = "TEXT" >');
HTP.P('<p id="demo"></p>');
htp.p('<script type="text/javascript">function myFunction() {/**Call the other stored procedure here passing the value from the the element "demo"**/');          
htp.p('</script>');
HTP.P('<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Personal Info</button>');
HTP.p('<p>This example demonstrates how to assign an "onclick" event to a p element.</p>');
htp.p('<H1>Personal Info For '||v_first_name||' '||v_last_name||'</H1>');
htp.p('</BODY>');
htp.p('</HTML>');
END;
```

I Want to pass the value of the element "Demo" as a parameter.

Is this possible? and how can this be achieved?

Comment: If I understand you right, you want to execute a Stored Procedure inside the JavaScript part and pass the value from the element Demo as parameter? If that's want you want, I would suggest to use AJAX

Comment: @Ovoxo your understanding is correct however I would like to know how this could be achieved in pl/sql as I am not aware of the syntax nor the packages that might enable me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how to do a AJAX-Request.
I couldn't test it.
As you see you need to change the values on `http.open` witht the name of your procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE hello_world
IS
    v_first_name   VARCHAR2 (30) := 'ABC';
    v_last_name    VARCHAR2 (30) := 'XYZ';
BEGIN
    HTP.p ('<HTML>');
    HTP.p ('<HEAD>');
    HTP.p ('<TITLE>Instructor Personal Info</TITLE>');
    HTP.p ('</HEAD>');
    HTP.p ('<BODY bgColor="#99CCCC">');
    HTP.p ('<input type="text" name = "TEXT" >');
    HTP.p ('<p id="demo"></p>');
    HTP.p('<script type="text/javascript">function myFunction() {
            var http;
            var response;

            var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
            http = new XMLHttpRequest();

            http.open("GET", "PROCEDURE_TO_CALL?param1="+ demo.value, false);

            http.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            http.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
                    response = http.responseText;
                }
            }

            http.send();
    }');
    HTP.p ('</script>');
    HTP.p('<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Personal Info</button>');
    HTP.p('<p>This example demonstrates how to assign an "onclick" event to a p element.</p>');
    HTP.p(   '<H1>Personal Info For '
          || v_first_name
          || ' '
          || v_last_name
          || '</H1>');
    HTP.p ('</BODY>');
    HTP.p ('</HTML>');
END;
```

Comment: Line 29, Char 13 throws the error: The system cannot locate the resource specified. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you change the name of the called procedure and the name of the parameter?

Comment: I changed the Procedure name with my procedure name and the parameter to pass is actually demo.value. I think the parameter should be fine..